# write array elements to an excel sheet in shell script

Tags: excel, shell

<strike>I created two arrays in shell script</strike>

I create an array in shell script

```
arr1=(manoj 724409 suharsha 298427 koti 702984 sudhakar 283789 chaitanya 769235)
```

and I want that array elements in excel sheet as follows

```
name       arr1  
manoj      724409
suharsha   298427
koti       702984
sudhakar   283789
chaitanya  769235
```

<strike>I tried only for single array(arr1) that also not worked</strike>

here is the code that I tried

```
str=`echo -e 'name\t arr1\t arr2\n'`

i=0
len=${#arr1[@]}
while [ $i -lt $len ]
do
    str="${str}${arr1[$i]}"
    str=`echo -e $str'\t'`
    if [[ ${arr1[$i]} =~ [0-9]{1} ]]; then
        str=`echo -e $str'\n'`
    fi
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done

awk '{print $str}' > output.xls
```

I modified my question. I don't need to store both array's information. Just one is enough.

Comment: So your question is how to convert `$arr1` valuels into the 12 lines of output shown in your sample? Also, what are you doing that data must be in `$arr1` ? Why not just `program_that_produces_output_used_in_arr1 | script_to_create_required_outFile > outFile.xls`? (This would be really easy). Good luck.

Comment: Will you really need a dynamic solution that can output as many columns as needed, or do you really just want key=value pairs (essentially). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code does not produce a viable result is because the .xls format is not a plaintext format. So let's back up:

Are you attempting to write an excel sheet, or an excel compatible format?

- If you can use an excel compatible format, excel (and libre-office) are capable of reading .csv files.
- If you need the .xls/xlsx format, you will need some sort of library / application to do the writing.

Additionally are you using a windows machine, or a *nix machine?

- If on a *nix machine (as I am assuming, since you are asking about shellscript), then your only choice will be some sort of library or a .csv file.
- If on windows, then you could use powershell to spawn an Excel COM object. This will effectively let you control an active excel application in the background and create a sheet with it.

There are additional options of writing excel files if you are willing to leave the shell, but that's not in the scope of your question.

Comment: The `perl` language definitely has modules that can create and modify `.xlsx` format files. I would bet that `python` also has similar libraries, but I can't say for sure. Note that `.csv` certainly works, and `.tsv` is a little more *nix friendly, as it uses tab chars to separate fields. There are numerous tricks you can find that will help with adding minimal formatting to your cells and maybe some other simple things. Good luck to all.

Comment: thanks @delyeet . I accept your answer. And I know that my code doesn't produce viable result. I want to know that where I did mistake and I need the right code which satisfies my requirement.